# Get spinner id as defined in xml

Tags: android, spinner

In my Android app I have a spinner and use a resource file to set the values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="radius">
        <item id="100">100 m</item>
        <item id="500">500 m</item>
        <item>1 km</item>
        <item>5 km</item>
        <item>10 km</item>
        <item>15 km</item>
        <item>20 km</item>
        <item>30 km</item>
        <item>40 km</item>
        <item>50 km</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

It isn't clear how I retrieve the id field when an item is selected. The samples I see posted on SO show how to get the value but I need to get the id. The values are language dependent, so I need to rely upon the id to determine what item was selected. I can't rely upon the position because the values will be sorted which results in a different sort order for different languages.

Comment: I want the id of the item and NOT the spinner. In the above sample, the first item has an id of 100, the 2nd 500.

Comment: why don't you take the text itself that will be much easier. As in your case the ID and the Text are the same. You just need to trim the later part.

Comment: How about I replace my example above and use text like "Holiday" (english) and then use a german list with "Urlaub". You're missing the point. List values that use text and come in different languages need an ID to clearly distinguish between the items. The position of one value in one list may not match up to the position within a different list when the lists are sorted alphabetically. That's why IDs are used.

Comment: AFAIK, Android doesn't support attribute in `item` for XML resource. Use two `string-arrays`: one for `id` and one for `radius`, and when you select the `radius` on the spinner, get the `id` by using the selected position.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use the onItemSelectedListner..

Try this

```
    yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        Message mSelected = (Message) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        Log.i("Id:", mSelected.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Message", "Nothing is selected");

    }


});
```